# Keep values of numpy array that satisfy two or more conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to keep values of an array that satisfy two or more conditions, for example:

```
a = np.array([1,3,5,6,4,6,7,8,9])
```

I want to keep only values that are greater than 3 and less than 7, my desired output is:

```
array([5, 6, 4, 6])
```

I see one way to do it :

```
a = a[(a > 3) * (a < 7)]
```

But something about this multiplications feels redundant, and I think that I am missing a built-in method for something like this.

Comment: to my knowledge there is no shorter way, and to be honest, this one is not too redundant: It says exactly what you want concisely, an array from a, where the item is less than 7 and greater than 3

Comment: Usually you would do `a[(a > 3) & (a < 7)]`

Comment: @jamylak, I new I was missing something :). Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:
I corrected it to reflect the use of numpy array.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
a =np.array([1,3,5,6,4,6,7,8,9])
t1= timeit.Timer('a[(a > 3) * (a < 7)]', 'from __main__ import a' )
t2= timeit.Timer('a[(a > 3) & (a < 7)]','from __main__ import a')
t3 =timeit.Timer('[e for e in a if e < 7 and e > 3]','from __main__ import a')


print t1.timeit(1000)/1000
print t2.timeit(1000)/1000
print t3.timeit(1000)/1000


>>> 
1.01280212402e-05
1.23770236969e-05
1.51431560516e-05
```

Running it a second time

```
1.06210708618e-05
1.16641521454e-05
1.76239013672e-05
```